# How to configure webpack and Typescript to exclude resolving a specific typing-only package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using only the types package of `@types/aws-lambda` for type declaration within my code. I'm not using its actual package, just its typings.

In my code, I would still import the typings as though it is a normal module though, something like this:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

const myApi: APIGatewayEvent = someEvent;
```

However, when I try to compile through webpack, I get an error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-lambda' in...`.

Is this an issue with webpack or Typescript trying to resolve the module? How can I configure webpack and in tsconfig to exclude attempting to resolve `aws-lambda` which in my case is only the typings to resolve the error?

Comment: the usage of `APIGatewayEvent` was typo-ed as `ApiGatewayEvent`. I'm assuming that's unrelated to your issue?

Comment: With the typo fixed, the code you provided appears to be working for me. Is there something specific in your webpack config, tsconfig or is this package depended on by _another_ package (peer dependency?)?

Comment: @skovy Ahh... thanks for editing my typo. I didn't have that typo in my code though. I'm not sure if there are any peer dependency on this package, but I just realise that I don't get this error when I don't declare and use my own decorator. When I declare my decorator, which also doesn't use this package other than its typings, the error will occur.

Comment: Is `aws-lambda` a file that you created in your `src` directory? If so, you'll need to include the path to the file.

`import { APIGatewayEvent } from './path/to/file/aws-lambda';`

Comment: @automasean The `aws-lambda` is a package from npm. But I have only installed its `@types` package without the actual package because I only needed its typings.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for clarifying! I'm able to get it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-pike-k9oco?fontsize=14). Try some of the suggestions I've made in my answer. Hopefully it's a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring webpack to [resolve `.ts` extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions).

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  }
};
```

Also make sure you have the proper [TypeScript integration configuration](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/).

You can also double-check your `tsconfig.json` file. If you're explicitly setting `typeRoots` then you'll want to include `"./node_modules/@types"`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

in typescript, first, you need to tell tsc compiler, this is a new module. for that, You need to add **declare** keyword. and also, in this case, you're using aws-lambda as an interface for real-time IntelliSense. for that you need to add **typeof** keyword. like that

```
import { APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';

declare const myApi: typeof APIGatewayEvent
```